# How to correctly format print using format in Python3 (with many arguments inside of print)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cs50, eof

I'm trying to run a simple program in Python3, but I keep getting this error message after typing into the terminal `python3 mario.py`:

```
  File "mario.py", line 10
                                                ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

I'm not sure why this is happening. Here is my code:

```
#from cs50 import get_int

height = int(input("Height: "))

if height < 1 or height > 8:
    height = get_int("Height: ")

for i in range(height):
    print(f"{"#" * i}  {"#" * i}\n", end="")
```

I believe it has something to do with the way I'm formatting my `print` function. I'm not sure which one of these to use: `'` or `"`
I would love if you could help!

Comment: You forgot to escape the `"` in the last print statement

Comment: Hey! Where, I can't find it. I tried this but it didn't work. Can you please retype or insert as an answer the correct code (and also if you can put it as an answer I can mark it as correct ;)

Comment: `print(f'{"  # " * i}  {"#" * i}\n', end="")`

Comment: Please use a proper IDE with syntax highlighting and you'll find such issues

Comment: ps. @ThomasWeller Love what you work with, keep up the good work

Comment: @ThomasWeller Used up all of my daily votes on you right now  hopefully it made a difference on your profile

Comment: @NicolasFuchs: unfortunately it doesn't. Stack Overflow cancels all the votes when you vote too much for a single person, because they suspect fraud. When that happens, it looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZCqT.png But it's ok, no need to upvote. Beyond 20.000, these Internet points become less and less meaningful

Comment: Ok! Hope you're doing fine in quarantine @ThomasWeller! Have a good week :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to alternate between `"` and `'`. Try this:
`print(f'{"  # " * i}  {"#" * i}\n', end="")`